# Spring Boot 2 NamedNativeQuery no property found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-2

I recently upgraded Spring Boot from 1.5.2 Release to Spring Boot 2.1.3 Release. And after that my application does not run because of **Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getPayments found for type DailyPaymentOrgFunc!**

Here is my entity :

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = Function.ORG_FUNC_NAME,query = Function.ORG_FUNC,
        callable = true,resultClass = DailyPaymentOrgFunc.class)
public class DailyPaymentOrgFunc{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECEIPT_NUMBER")
    private String receiptNumber;
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Float amount;
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_CODE")
    private Integer serviceCode;
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_DATE")
    private Date paymentDate;
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_TRN")
    private String paymentTrn;
    @Column(name = "ORG_CODE")
    private Integer orgCode;
}
```

Repository :

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface DailyPaymentOrgRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyPaymentOrgFunc,String> {
    List<DailyPaymentOrgFunc> getPayments(@Param("orgCode") Integer orgCode);
}
```

Constant Class :

```
public class Function {


    public static final String ORG_FUNC_NAME = "DailyPaymentOrgFunc.getPayments";

    public static final String ORG_FUNC ="{ ? = call DAILY_PAYMENT_FUNC(null,2,:orgCode,null)}";

    private Function() throws IllegalAccessException {
        throw new IllegalAccessException("Function is a utility class!!!");
    }
}
```

I debugged the code and found out that the problem is this piece of code at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.class, this piece of code **return (TypeInformation)((Optional)this.fieldTypes.computeIfAbsent(fieldname, this::getPropertyInformation)).orElse((Object)null);** return Optional null, that is why it is not working, but I do not know how to fix this problem.

```
 @Nullable
public TypeInformation<?> getProperty(String fieldname) {
    int separatorIndex = fieldname.indexOf(46);
    if (separatorIndex == -1) {
        return (TypeInformation)((Optional)this.fieldTypes.computeIfAbsent(fieldname, this::getPropertyInformation)).orElse((Object)null);
    } else {
        String head = fieldname.substring(0, separatorIndex);
        TypeInformation<?> info = this.getProperty(head);
        return info == null ? null : info.getProperty(fieldname.substring(separatorIndex + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: where is that `TypeDiscoverer` code from ?  spring-data-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar doesn't have that.`@Nullable
 public TypeInformation<?> getProperty(String fieldname) {

  int separatorIndex = fieldname.indexOf('.');

  if (separatorIndex == -1) {
   return fieldTypes.computeIfAbsent(fieldname, this::getPropertyInformation).orElse(null);
  }

  String head = fieldname.substring(0, separatorIndex);
  TypeInformation<?> info = getProperty(head);

  if (info == null) {
   return null;
  }

  return info.getProperty(fieldname.substring(separatorIndex + 1));
 }`

Comment: @user3487063 spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar has it.

Comment: 2.1.5.RELEASE has this: `@Nullable
 public TypeInformation<?> getProperty(String fieldname) {

  int separatorIndex = fieldname.indexOf('.');

  if (separatorIndex == -1) {
   return fieldTypes.computeIfAbsent(fieldname, this::getPropertyInformation).orElse(null);
  }

  String head = fieldname.substring(0, separatorIndex);
  TypeInformation<?> info = getProperty(head);

  if (info == null) {
   return null;
  }

  return info.getProperty(fieldname.substring(separatorIndex + 1));
 }`

Comment: do you see 46 in code ? this line : `fieldname.indexOf(46);` thats ascii for '.' though

Comment: @user3487063 after downloading source it is like you said, I just haven't downloaded the source code